# recommended way to segregate huge osm file

Tags: google-maps, gis, openstreetmap, osmosis

i have osm data structured as shown in fig1 below. what i want to do is, to extract 3 files out of the main file shown in the fig1, so that each file is
organised as shown in figures 2,3,4

to do that, i implemented a segregator algorithm to fragment the main file "fig1" into small chuncks.

my question is, is there any software or better approach to that instead of writing segregation algorith?

**fig1**:

[image]

**fig2**:

[image]

**fig3**:

[image]

**fig4**:

[image]

Comment: What are you segregating by? Id? Location? How did you segregate - where's your code?

Comment: @MarkSetchell using Stax library..it is for processing xml files

Comment: You still haven't told us what your separation criterion is.

Comment: @scai i thought it is obvious and can be easily grasped from the code posted above...anyway, the criterion is, to segregate each bunch of nodes and their relevant tag element and write them to a .xml file

Comment: @user2121 No its not because this is *not* a typical [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) file. The *tag* element does *not* belong to the *node* since it is obviously separated and not enclosed by the corresponding `<node></node>` tags. Where did you get this broken OSM file from?

Comment: Also it could be very helpful to tell us what your ultimate goal is. There are already lots of different OSM tools for various jobs available

Comment: @scai i want to extract speed limit information from the map data according to a given lat and long..would u please tell me what is the advisable approach dealing with this problem...given that the osm data is really huge and we want to retrieve information effeciently

Comment: Take a look at [osmfilter](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) or [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Comment: @scai maybe this could be a question fro you as well :)      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203228/how-to-query-osm-from-the-server

Comment: maxspeed details are in most cases tagged on OSM ways rather than nodes like in your (non-OSM data model conformant) example. I'd suggest to get familiar with the OSM data model a bit more, read the [Wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed) before trying to automate things.