# How to query OSM from the server

Tags: android, web-services, openstreetmap, overpass-api, osmosis

Is there any way to connect to the web server of OpenStreetMap?

I want to receive the speed limit information given a geoLoc "lat and Lon". I thought of solving this issue by creating a huge database encompases
the node's lat and lon and the speed limit and then query the speed limit given a specific geoLoc.

but now i am wondering is it possible to connect directly the OSM server and query the speed limit given a specific geoLoc?! whic approach is more
efficient?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) for querying (almost) any information. The [language guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) even has a very similar problem to yours: [querying for name and rough location](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#By_exact_name_and_rough_location). Just replace the name tag with the maxspeed tag and you are almost done.

Overpass API has a really powerful language which can be quite a bit confusing at first. It might help you running your queries via the [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) frontend which has a nice visualization of the results.

Comment: is it possible to connect and query from android devices

Comment: Sure, why not? The API is accessible via HTTP.